# Firebase function for storage trigger functions.storage.object().onFinalize() exits without waiting for asyn call

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to parse a firebase storage excel file to json using firebase cloud functions.

My code executes but I see that the firebase storage function exists without waiting for async call to get the file from storage and parse it. I tried many combinations ... Not sure where I am going wrong. Help please as I am stuck!

```
/***********   index.js --> STORAGE TRIGGERS FUNCTIONS     *********************/

exports.rawdataToJSON = 
   functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
   rawdataToJSON.handler(object, database);
 });
```

Comment: You say you're using Firebase, but I don't see that anywhere at all in your code.  There's no Cloud Storage trigger that I can see, and I don't see where you use the firebase-functions module, which is required to define the function using Firebase tools.

Comment: Hi . ... updated the post to show the call that I make from index.js

Comment: Background functions like yours need to return a promise that resolves after all the async work is complete. Read the documentation for more details.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: Doug... you correct. I forgot that I need to return promise to keep it alive. Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Answer (score 0):

the index.js function should be returning a promise.

```
/***********   STORAGE TRIGGERS FUNCTIONS     *********************/

exports.rawdataToJSONFunction = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) 
=> {
  return rawdataToJSONFunction.handler(object, database);
});
```